# How to merge Car Stock Totals by Colors in MySQL/SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have two car shops and each shop has 12 different models of cars. The cars are of different models and colors. There are also a few cars of the same color, of the same model.

That's why I want to count all the cars in both stores according to the number of colors.
Ny fiddle is below:

[Sample fiddle database is here:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cf133e6bb7aa3ad834ea648dbfb684e)

I have query in above link but query only counts CompanyA or CompanyB total. How can I find grand total of cars and color in our stock?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Your table structure is kinda weird?
Having 1 row represent stock in both stores? What if there is one car less in one store? or if there are more black cars in one store?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969271/how-to-count-car-colors-by-car-models-in-mysql-sql#comment125459283_70969271

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was asked just a few hours ago, by another account. Most probably multi-account user.

Comment: Yeah - change the original question to include more info - keep the fiddle that's good. However this seems like you are asking at the end of a process where you have gone wrong from the start.
Perhaps try to describe what you end goal and paramaters are, as it is now your design seems a mess!

Comment: Hi, Søren Kongstad yes, currently 12 car models and 9 colors here. If we will have black I will modify query no issue. Also if one car model missing any store I will handle it or we can show as 0 unit as well.

Comment: Hi jarlh, I already updated database , query and question. Pls. keep this one. Your shared link is not active. I am single user not multi. Thanks

Comment: I can't see the point of this design. I would do this 
"create table cars (id int, store varchar(50),model varchar(50),color varchar(50));"
Then issue insert statements like "values (1,'storeA','BMW','Pink'),(1,'storeB','Honda','Pink')"

Comment: With like that if store and/or car model increase also colors database will be huge. Maybe I can make store table (storeA, storeB,...) and keep car details in car db as well. This is sample db so I want to keep all of them in table. Because my question is little unique, with multiple table I count easily, only point is if all data in one table.

Comment: Also I can do same in excel but my data is in mysql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b74786421c932727b5c3200e20c759a6

Do your table like this:

```
create table cars(
id int
, store varchar(50)
,model varchar(50)
,color varchar(50)
);
```

Then add the same data:

```
(1,'storeA','Mercedes','Green')
,(2,'storeA','Kia','Grey')
,(3,'storeA','Lexus','Yellow')
,(4,'storeA','Lexus','Green')
,(5,'storeA','Lexus','Pink')
,(6,'storeA','Lexus','Pink')
,(7,'storeA','Mazda','White')
,(8,'storeA','Mazda','White')
,(9,'storeA','Mazda','Grey')
,(10,'storeA','Mazda','Brown')
,(11,'storeA','Kia','Brown')
,(12,'storeA','Nissan','White')
,(13,'storeA','Nissan','White')
,(14,'storeA','Nissan','Purple')
,(15,'storeA','Subaru','Blue')
,(16,'storeA','Subaru','Green')
,(17,'storeA','Toyota','Blue')
,(18,'storeA','Toyota','Purple')
,(19,'storeA','Toyota','White')
,(20,'storeA','Toyota','Purple')
,(21,'storeA','Honda','White')
,(22,'storeA','BMW','Red')
,(23,'storeA','BMW','Purple')
,(24,'storeA','Ford','Yellow')
,(25,'storeA','Ford','Green')
,(26,'storeA','Ford','Yellow')
,(27,'storeA','Ford','Grey')
,(28,'storeA','Honda','Green')
,(29,'storeA','Honda','White')
,(30,'storeA','Honda','White')
,(31,'storeA','BMW','Pink')
,(32,'storeA','Honda','White')
,(33,'storeA','Hyundai','Pink')
,(34,'storeA','Hyundai','Green')
,(35,'storeA','Hyundai','Green')
,(36,'storeA','Hyundai','Green')
,(37,'storeA','Jeep','Purple')
,(38,'storeA','Jeep','Pink')
,(39,'storeA','Jeep','Purple')
,(40,'storeA','Jeep','Yellow')
,(41,'storeB','BMW','Green')
,(42,'storeB','Ford','Grey')
,(43,'storeB','Jeep','Yellow')
,(44,'storeB','Jeep','Green')
,(45,'storeB','Toyota','Pink')
,(46,'storeB','Toyota','Pink')
,(47,'storeB','Ford','White')
,(48,'storeB','Jeep','White')
,(49,'storeB','Nissan','Grey')
,(50,'storeB','Nissan','Brown')
,(51,'storeB','Ford','Brown')
,(52,'storeB','Ford','White')
,(53,'storeB','Mazda','White')
,(54,'storeB','Mazda','Purple')
,(55,'storeB','Honda','Blue')
,(56,'storeB','Honda','Green')
,(57,'storeB','Hyundai','Blue')
,(58,'storeB','Hyundai','Purple')
,(59,'storeB','Jeep','White')
,(60,'storeB','Lexus','Purple')
,(61,'storeB','Subaru','White')
,(62,'storeB','Mercedes','Red')
,(63,'storeB','Mercedes','Purple')
,(64,'storeB','Kia','Yellow')
,(65,'storeB','Kia','Green')
,(66,'storeB','Mazda','Yellow')
,(67,'storeB','Nissan','Grey')
,(68,'storeB','BMW','Green')
,(69,'storeB','Subaru','White')
,(70,'storeB','Subaru','White')
,(71,'storeB','Honda','Pink')
,(72,'storeB','Subaru','White')
,(73,'storeB','Toyota','Pink')
,(74,'storeB','Toyota','Green')
,(75,'storeB','Toyota','Green')
,(76,'storeB','Toyota','Green')
,(77,'storeB','Lexus','Purple')
,(78,'storeB','Lexus','Pink')
,(79,'storeB','Mazda','Purple')
,(80,'storeB','Toyota','Yellow')
```

You can then pivot the data to colors either with stores:

```
select store,
model,
 SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Pink' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Pink',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Red',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Purple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Purple',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Yellow',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Green',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Grey' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Grey',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'White' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'White',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Brown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Brown',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Blue'
from cars
group by store,model
```

or across stores:

```
select model,
 SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Pink' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Pink',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Red',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Purple' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Purple',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Yellow' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Yellow',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Green',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Grey' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Grey',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'White' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'White',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Brown' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Brown',
         SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Blue'
from cars
group by model
```